# Android Media Player does not stopped

Tags: android, media-player

I have created an android app in that use one Media-Player to start a music when app is start and stop when app is stopped.

In my app the Media-Player doesn't stopped.

My code is:

```
public void StartPlayer()
{   
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.siren);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);   
    mPlayer.start();        
}
public void StopPlayer()
{
    if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: also try  `mPlayer.reset();`  after `mPlayer.stop();`

Comment: Are you sure that `StopPlayer` is called?

Comment: yeah @MalaKa using Log I check it. But Media Player does not stopped.

Comment: @SimplePlan I use mPlayer.reset(); but it not works.

Comment: Hm, I can not see any error.. The only thing I could imagine is that you set `mPlayer = null` somewhere so that the if-clause is not true and therefore the player does not stop. The second possibility I see is that you have somehow deklared two `mPlayer` variables ( within a handler or `onCreate` or something like that).

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem by making the mediaplayer object static (then it must be only one instance of the object).

Answer (score 0):

I have a working media player that starts and stops

```
Uri ringtone;
MediaPlayer mp;

ringtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), ringtone);

//code to start the mediaplayer

 if (Flags.notificationReceived) {
                    showAlert(Flags.patientModel);
                    Flags.notificationReceived = false;
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    vibrate(2000);
                }

//code to stop the media player

 if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), ringtone);
                }
```